# Sending POST Requests in Watin

Tags: post, automation, request, http-post, watin

I am trying to do send a POST request on a web page with Basic Authentication. So is there any samples showing how to automate sending POST Requests in Watin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that [this post](https://www.kongsli.net/2008/07/07/sending-post-requests-with-watin/) works

```
IE _ie = new IE();
object flags = null;
object targetFrame = null;
object headers = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" + Convert.ToChar(10) + Convert.ToChar(13);
object postDataBytes = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("{ mydata: 5 }");
object resourceLocator = "http://google.com";
IWebBrowser2 browser = (IWebBrowser2)_ie.InternetExplorer;
browser.Navigate2(ref resourceLocator, ref flags, ref targetFrame, ref postDataBytes, ref headers);
_ie.WaitForComplete();
```

My document is a json response and I'm still working on getting access to its raw contents via WatiN - currently it is being prompted to download.